# A method with an unspecified number of Generic Type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

Is there a way to work with an unspecified number of Generic Type Parameters in a method?

Effectively what I want to do is something like this except for the obvious issue:

```
    private static void FetchChunk(int retries, KeyValuePair<List<dynamic>,Type>[] fetchfields)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var chunk in fetchfields)
            {
                var obj = chunk.Key;
                obj = DBRepository.GetAll<chunk.Value>().ToList();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //do stuff
        }

    }
```

However this fails because instead of Type, I need to use a Generic Type paramater such as T

The problem is however, I don't know how use generics in such a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve. Since I would want a unique generic type parameter for each KeyValuePair in the array.

This on the other hand, absolutely compiles, but doesn't do what I am intending which is each KeyValue pair would have it's own unique Generic Type parameters.

```
    private static void FetchChunk<T>(int retries, KeyValuePair<List<dynamic>, T>[] fetchfields)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var chunk in fetchfields)
            {
                var obj = chunk.Key;
                obj = DBRepository.GetAll<T>().ToList();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

The method signature of GetAll is

```
 public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll(Type type, string columnNames = "*")
```

This doesn't work either:

```
                var type = chunk.Value.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                obj = DBRepository.GetAll<type>().ToList();
```

Is there a way to re-code this method in order to achieve my intentions?

Comment: Use Reflection.

Comment: I am not as familiar with reflection. l have used it before for other things, but nothing like this. Can you give an example?

Comment: Show the code for `DBRepository.GetAll<T>()`

Comment: I don't have the code myself. but the method signature looks like this :  public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll<T>(string columnNames = "*");

Comment: Can you change that code to be `public static IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAll(Type type, string columnNames = "*")` then use `type` in the method to get a non generic method for getting the result set.

Comment: Its in a library that I don't have the code to. I can't modify it.

Comment: @EricLippert I believe I need to something that is the inverse of this: Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use reflection in the wrapping method then as described in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) you should be able to construct the instance of the generic method using `MakeGenericMethod` and then call it with different set of types.

**Code updated to match the latest comment from @AlexanderRyanBaggett**

```
private static void FetchChunk(int retries, KeyValuePair<List<dynamic>, Type>[] fetchfields)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var chunk in fetchfields)
        {
            var method = typeof(DBRepository).GetMethod("GetAll");
            var Generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(chunk.Value);
            chunk.Key.AddRange(Generic.Invoke(null, null) as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //do stuff } }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I have just fixed a bug in the Invoke.. please make sure you are using latest version.

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for, but It has the key to solution in it.

Comment: This is what works :          private static void FetchChunk(int retries, KeyValuePair<List<dynamic>,Type>[] fetchfields)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var chunk in fetchfields)
                {
                    var method = typeof(DBRepository).GetMethod("GetAll");
                    var Generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(chunk.Value);
                    chunk.Key.AddRange(Generic.Invoke(null, null)as IEnumerable<dynamic>);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }

Comment: Update the answer with your latest code. I am glad it helped.